# Where does the "Click Reports" link_id come from in MailChimp's API v3?

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

In the "Click Report Members" endpoints, does anybody know where the "link_id" comes from? The docs just say it's "The id for the link."

https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/click-details/members/

Answer (score 1):

I found it. You get the "id" for each tracked link from the following API endpoint in the "urls_clicked" parameter of the response:

GET /reports/{campaign_id}/click-details

https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/click-details/#read-get_reports_campaign_id_click_details